# DSpace - OAI HARVESTER - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, dspace, harvest, oai

I'm experiencing difficulties with OAI harvesting. [My application](http://bidtest.epn.edu.ec/oai/request?verb=ListRecords&resumptionToken=oai_dc////3600) keeps failing with the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException : Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I ran all OAI related commands properly, which suggests that the problem comes from my DSpace. I haven't been able to identify the source of the errors because my log files aren't showing me anything unusual.

How can I go about tracking down the source of this issue?

Comment: What version of DSpace are you running?  If you do not see any useful information in the DSpace log file, try looking at the tomcat log file (catalina.out) for more information.

Comment: That entrance url looks weird. Do you also get nullpointers when you try standard URLs like request?verb=ListRecords&metadataPrefix=oai_dc or request?verb=Identify